# App crashes in simulator but not on device

Tags: objective-c, rubymotion

I am building an iOS app using Rubymotion and when I run the project in the simulator I get this error:

```
app_delegate.rb:31:in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:': NSInvalidArgumentException: -[NSNull pointSize]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1639cd8 (RuntimeError)
```

But when I run it on the device it does not crash.
I got iOS 6 on the device and iOS5 on the simulator.

*This is the line that crashes:*

```
UINavigationController.alloc.initWithRootViewController(firstViewController)
```

When I comment out all instances of *setTitleTextAttributes* in the app it works.
This is a few examples of how I use it:

```
aboutController.tabBarItem.setTitleTextAttributes({UITextAttributeFont => tabFont}, forState:UIControlStateNormal)

aboutNavController.navigationBar.setTitleTextAttributes({UITextAttributeFont => titleFont})
```

I guess it is a iOS5 issue? Am I using it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your navigationBar titleTextAttributes need to be set like an accessor:

```
aboutNavController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = {UITextAttributeFont => titleFont}
```

Apple docs reference:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html